# How to get date & time using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to get the start date and end date in the below format using moment js

startDate = 20160427000000 and 
endDate = 20160427235959

Here the start date appended with 000000 and end date appended with 235959

What is the right way to get this result in javascript

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... are you trying to parse the date and time out separately given the 20160427000000 and 20160427235959 as inputs?

Comment: Perhaps you want to output dates in that format? If so, then `moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')`.

Comment: Yes I want to give  as input in this format

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill No these are not inputs...I will give inputs as 2016/04/27 and I need to get output like above

Answer (score 2):

You want the `format` operator. Since it looks like your 0's and 2359's are hardcoded (I assume you're doing start and end of days), try:

```
startDate = moment().format('YMMDD000000');
endDate = moment().format('YMMDD235959');
```

**EDIT:** Or, as RobG pointed out, you can use:

```
startDate = moment().startOf('day').format("YMMDDHHmmss");
endDate = moment().endOf('day').format("YMMDDHHmmss");
```

(Which is much neater)

Comment: Or `moment().endOf('day').format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')`.

Comment: @RobG For start date how i need to give??

Comment: @RobG why the Year is mentioned as Y instead of YYYY

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally confused, I don't know if you want to parse the format or output it. If you want to parse dates using moment.js in that format, then in time zone +05:30:

```
// Format YYYYMMDDHHmmss for 2016-04-26T00:00:00
var s = '20160426000000';
var x = moment(s, 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss');

// Show date in ISO 8601 extended format
console.log(x.format()); // 2016-04-26T00:00:00+05:30
```

To shift to the end of the day and output in YYYMMDDHHmmss format:

```
console.log(x.endOf('day').format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')); // 20160426235959
```

In the format string:

- YYYY is 4 digit year
- MM is two digit month
- DD is two digit day
- HH is two digit hour in 24 hour format
- mm is two digit minute
- ss is two digit seconds

Answer (score 0):

**For Getting Format Like these in moment.js - (2020-12-15T13:00:00)**

**let a** =2023-01-14T20:15:00-05:00

You can use moment(a).format("**YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss**")

**Result:** 2023-01-14T20:15:00